# facebook api fan page user list

Tags: facebook

is it possible to get list of uids of users who is fan of specific fan page with facebook api ?

Comment: i'm sure it isn't actually possible to do this - but is it perhaps possible to get verification that a particular user is a fan?

Answer (score 2):

I have not (yet) found a method to retrieve all the fans for a page without a key.

You can get a verification if a user is a fan, according to [Facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/pages.isFan) at least. In practice, use of the method still requires a key.

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually looking for thesame thing, and from the looks of it, the answer is no. User list is not one of the properties you can read according to [this page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page).